# JavaScript script in thymeleaf doesn't run on page load?

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
            console.log("Hello world");
        </script>

        <h1 th:text="${makeCodeName}"></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my thymeleaf file. I want to make a GET Request and add some buttons to the page when the page loads, but my script doesn't want to run? What am I doing wrong here?

```
    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/makes/{makeCodeName}")
    public String showCarModels(@PathVariable String makeCodeName, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("makeCodeName", makeCodeName);
        return "testMakes";
    }
```

This is how I am showing the page...

Comment: If your script is the same as you added there, it's just a `console.log`

Comment: How do you know it is not running? Press f12, go to console and look for the log. You may want to do alert('Hello World')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike normal HTML, you need to restart your Spring server after each change to your Thymeleaf template..

Comment: It is only necessary to re-build if you import the spring developer tools.